# How to fix SQL query with Left Join and subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, left-join

I have SQL query with LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT COUNT(stn.stocksId) AS count_stocks
FROM MedicalFacilities AS a
LEFT JOIN stocks stn ON 
(stn.stocksIdMF = ( SELECT b.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser 
                        FROM medicalfacilities AS b 
                        WHERE b.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser = a.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser 
                        ORDER BY stn.stocksId DESC LIMIT 1) 

AND stn.stocksEndDate >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AND stn.stocksStartDate <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
```

These query I want to select one row from table `stocks` by conditions and with field equal value `a.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser`.

I get always `count_stocks = 0` in result. But I need to get `1`

Comment: Are you sure about `stn.stocksEndDate >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AND stn.stocksEndDate <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`? Seems it should be replace'able by just `stn.stocksEndDate = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, but I doubt that's what you mean to do.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: good point, or maybe `UNIX_TIMESTAMP() between stn.stocksStartDate and stn.StocksEndDate`

Comment: Yes, one problem was in condition with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. Updated question

Comment: I think that is wrong sub-query, because I need select one row from `stocks`

Comment: Now the query has start and end time mixed. Start time should be smaller than the current timestamp, not larger.

Comment: Changed, but problem is still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery seems redundant and main query is hard to read as much of the join statements could be placed in where clause. Additionally, original query might have a performance issue.

Recall `WHERE` is an implicit join and `JOIN` is an explicit join. Query optimizers 
make no distinction between the two if they use same expressions but readability and maintainability is another thing to acknowledge.

Consider the revised version (notice I added a `GROUP BY`):

```
SELECT COUNT(stn.stocksId) AS count_stocks 
FROM MedicalFacilities AS a 
LEFT JOIN stocks stn ON stn.stocksIdMF = a.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser
WHERE stn.stocksEndDate >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
  AND stn.stocksStartDate <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
GROUP BY stn.stocksId
ORDER BY stn.stocksId DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The `count(...)` aggregate doesn't count `null`, so its argument matters:

```
COUNT(stn.stocksId)
```

Since `stn` is your right hand table, this will not count anything if the `left join` misses.  You could use:

```
COUNT(*)
```

which counts every row, even if all its columns are `null`.  Or a column from the left hand table (`a`) that is never `null`:

```
COUNT(a.ID)
```

Comment: I can not use `count(*)` because I have some others `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery in the `on` looks very strange to me:

```
on stn.stocksIdMF = ( SELECT b.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser 
                      FROM medicalfacilities AS b 
                      WHERE b.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser = a.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser 
                      ORDER BY stn.stocksId DESC LIMIT 1)
```

This is comparing `MedicalFacilitiesIdUser` to `stocksIdMF`.  Admittedly, you have no sample data or data layouts, but the naming of the columns suggests that these are not the same thing.  Perhaps you intend:

```
on stn.stocksIdMF = ( SELECT b.stocksId 
-----------------------------^
                      FROM medicalfacilities AS b 
                      WHERE b.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser = a.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser 
                      ORDER BY b.stocksId DESC
                      LIMIT 1)
```

Also, ordering by `stn.stocksid` wouldn't do anything useful, because that would be coming from *outside* the subquery.